# xsession-errors

Tags: bash, login, lightdm, gui

when I logged in to my desktop and listed the contents of the `.xsession-errors` file in my home directory, the following is found . kindly let me know what to do to correct the errors

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/config-err-XXXXXX’: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
truncate: cannot open ‘’ for writing: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
truncate: cannot open ‘’ for writing: No such file or directory
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
 init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
```

As requested the output of `ls -ld /tmp` is furnished below:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct  1 15:17 /tmp
```

the owner and the group seems to be root and how to correct

Also, my bash shell is regularly crashing now

Comment: Do you experience any errors during your graphical session? The first line seems to indicate that `/tmp` is not writable. Please append the output of `ls -ld /tmp` to your question by editing it.

Comment: this is the output of ls -ld /tmp drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct  1 14:17 /tmp

Comment: 1.) Please don't put any further output in comments. Below your question, there is a field 'edit'. Use it and append the output to your original post! 2.) The permissions are wrong. As they are now, only root may write to `/tmp`.

Comment: Did you get the issue resolved? If my answer answer solved it for you, consider accepting it. Otherwise please ask back! Don't want to leave it unresolved :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the excerpt from `.xsession-errors` posted, shows that `/tmp` cannot be written to. This is confirmed by the output of `ls -ld /tmp` showing permissions 755 for `/tmp`, when they should be 1777 (read/write/execute permissions for everyone + sticky bit, so only `root` can remove the directory).

To rectify this, do

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

**Edit**: As terdon mentions quite rightfully in the comments, the display manager (tested with `gdm` and `lightdm`) automatically restarts when you log out from the graphical shell (Unity, GNOME,...). And with it, the X-server is also restarted. No need to do it manually.

---

Take the following as a reference, if you ever need to restart `lightdm` for some other reason.

Restart the X-Server and see if this error and hopefully the others as well are gone. It should be enough to restart the session manager. Log out from your graphical session.

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a console.
- Login with your credentials and do

  ```
  sudo service lightdm restart
  ```

---

**Note:** It might be that you need to set the approriate permissons 1777 for `/tmp/.X11-unix`. See [this post on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/what-are-common-rights-for-tmp-i-unintentionnally-set-it-all-public-recursive).

Comment: i will correct the chmod soon, by the by how to restart the X-server pl..

Comment: @user456495 See the edit. I believe it suffices to restart `lightdm`

Comment: Logging out from the graphical session and logging back in will restart the X server. No need to also use `service lightdm restart`.

Comment: @terdon. Maybe 'graphical session' was a poor choice of words. I meant logging out from the graphical shell, e.g Unity, GNOME, etc... This brings you back to the greeter. As I understand it, the X-Server is started by the display manager service at boot time. Does `lightdm` and hence X restart when you log out from e.g Unity?

Comment: It should, yes. Unless `lightdm` behaves very differently (I just checked with `gdm`). You can test this by comparing the output of `pgrep X` before and after logging out/back in again. If they're different, X has been restarted.

Comment: @terdon Quite right. lightdm behaves the same. Thank you for the notice!